# Newtonsoft.Json parses incorrect json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I encountered a weird problem: given such string `{"text":"s","cursorPosition":189,"dataSource":"json_northwind",` which is not a correct json, it still gets succesfully parsed.

this is the class:

```
public class CompletionDataRequest
{
    public CompletionDataRequest(string text, int cursorPosition, string dataSource, string project)
    {
        Text = text;
        CursorPosition = cursorPosition;
        DataSource = dataSource;
        Project = project;
    }

    public string Text { get; }
    public int CursorPosition { get; }
    public string DataSource { get; }
    public string Project { get; }
}
```

Here is test that surprisingly succeeds:

```
var s = @"{""text"":""s"",""cursorPosition"":189,""dataSource"":""json_northwind"",";
var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompletionDataRequest>(s);
request.Text.Should().Be("s");
request.CursorPosition.Should().Be(189);
request.DataSource.Should().Be("json_northwind");
request.Project.Should().BeNull();
```

does the library have some loosened parsing rules or maybe this is a bug? I am library version 9.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

An issue [Deserializing unclosed object succeeds when the object has a parameterized constructor. #1038](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1038) was opened for this question.  It was fixed in [Json.NET release 10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1) in change set [0721bd4](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/0721bd4decd1d48f22e12c2cb881b0af91b05ca1).

**Original Answer**

You have found a bug in Json.NET.  It arises only when your object is constructed with a parameterized constructor.  If I modify your object to have a non-parameterized constructor:

```
public class CompletionDataRequest
{
    public CompletionDataRequest(string text, int cursorPosition, string dataSource, string project)
    {
        Text = text;
        CursorPosition = cursorPosition;
        DataSource = dataSource;
        Project = project;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private CompletionDataRequest()
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public int CursorPosition { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string DataSource { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Project { get; private set; }
}
```

Then Json.NET will correctly throw a `JsonSerializationException`.

The cause of the bug is as follows.  When creating an object with a parameterless constructor, Json.NET first constructs the object, then populates it with [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L2291).  This method has the following (simplified) logic:

```
    private object PopulateObject(object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, string id)
    {
        bool finished = false;
        do
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                {
                    // Read and process the property.
                }
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    finished = true;
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    // ignore
                    break;
                default:
                    throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Unexpected token when deserializing object: " + reader.TokenType);
            }
        } while (!finished && reader.Read());

        if (!finished)
        {
            ThrowUnexpectedEndException(reader, contract, newObject, "Unexpected end when deserializing object.");
        }

        return newObject;
     }
```

As you can see, there is logic `if (!finished)` to verify that the object is actually closed.

However, when creating an object with a parameterized constructor, the properties are read before the object is constructed, using [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L2115):

```
    private List<CreatorPropertyContext> ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
    {
        List<CreatorPropertyContext> propertyValues = new List<CreatorPropertyContext>();
        bool exit = false;
        do
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    // Read and process the property.
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Unexpected token when deserializing object: " + reader.TokenType);
            }
        } while (!exit && reader.Read());

        return propertyValues;
    }
```

As you can see there's no equivalent check for `exit` being true.

An issue [Deserializing unclosed object succeeds when the object has a parameterized constructor. #1038](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1038) was opened for this.

Comment: @Łukasz - OK, I went ahead and reported the issue, [Deserializing unclosed object succeeds when the object has a parameterized constructor. #1038](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1038).

Comment: Oh, I was in progress, but I will stop then. Thanks for help